# Problemas al arrancar un servidor JBoss

Tags: java, servidor, jdbc, jboss

Tengo un servidor JBoss montado y configurado, pero cada vez que arranco el servidor me sale el siguiente error:

```
16:50:01,699 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYCTL0013: Operación ("add") falló - dirección: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "com.sqlserver")
]) - descripción de la falla: "WFLYJCA0041: No se logró cargar el módulo para el controlador [com.sqlserver]"


16:50:06,099 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operación ("add") falló - dirección: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "/vp301bDS")
]) - descripción de la falla: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Servicios requeridos que aún no están instalados:" => [
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.sqljdbc4_jar",
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.sqljdbc4_jar"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Servicios con dependencias que faltan/no disponibles" => [
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/vp301bDS falta [jboss.jdbc-driver.sqljdbc4_jar]",
        "org.wildfly.data-source./vp301bDS falta [jboss.jdbc-driver.sqljdbc4_jar]",
        "org.wildfly.data-source./vp301bDS falta [jboss.jdbc-driver.sqljdbc4_jar]"
    ]
}
```

No termina de arrancar, pero si me permite ejecutar el localhost:9990, aunque no deja hacer más.

Mi archivo standalone.xml tiene configurada la sección datasources de la siguiente forma:

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/vp301bDS" pool-name="/vp301bDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://69.50.56.82/AvanteDXXS_Pruebas</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
    <driver>sqljdbc4.jar</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>user</user-name>
        <password>pwd</password>
    </security>
    </datasource>
         <drivers>
             <driver name="com.sqlserver" module="com.sqlserver">
                 <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</xa-datasource-class>
             </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

Es posible que tenga algo mal escrito o que tenga que mover algo de carpeta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu configuración de `jboss` esta buscando el [sqljdbc4.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsqljdbc420jar.htm) y al parecer no lo encuentra. Debes agregarlo a la carpeta `lib` de `jboss`. Aún así no va a a funcionar porque este jar depende de una dll [auth/x(86|64)/sqljdbc_auth.dll](https://www.microsoft.com/es-mx/download/details.aspx?id=11774) que proporciona microsoft y debes pegar también en `lib` desde la carpeta `auth` para que funcione. 
Pero yo te recomendaría usar el mssql-jdbc_6.1.0.jre8.jar que esta en maven ya que este no requiere dll para conectarse y lo puedes bajar así:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

El

> *< driver>**sqljdbc4.jar**</ driver>*

debería coincidir con el

> *<driver name="**com.sqlserver**"*

```
<driver>com.sqlserver</driver>
<security>
    <user-name>user</user-name>
    <password>pwd</password>
</security>
</datasource>
     <drivers>
         <driver name="com.sqlserver" module="com.sqlserver">
```

Comment: Deberías explicar mejor tu propuesta de solución.